# How to get locations from android device with internet/wifi without asking runtime permissions

Tags: android, location-services

My requirement is that to fetch users locations without asking GPS and runtime permissions.

Comment: This is not possible with any degree of accuracy, for obvious privacy reasons. The most that you can do with only the `INTERNET` permission is to use one of the various "geo IP" services online that will give you a location tied to the user's public IP address. This is what allows Web sites to guess your location (e.g., to suggest stores that are local to you). I have no idea how well these will work with mobile data, and they can be off by half a planet (e.g., user is using a VPN).

Answer (score 1):

From Android 6 it's not possible using GPS without runtime permission.